# Asymptotic scaling of mean and variance for non centered chi distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, asymptotics, variance, means, concentration-of-measure

Defined $Y \equiv \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^k(\frac{ X_i}{\sigma_i})^2}$, with $X_i \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_i, \sigma_i^2)$ it is known that Y is distributed as a non-central chi ([Noncentral chi distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncentral_chi_distribution)); how does the mean and variance of the distribution scale with k in the limit of $k \rightarrow \infty$?

Comment: difficult to say, the information concerning  $\mu_i$ and $\sigma_i$ is required.